# How can I have my npx script run commands within the same package/repo?

Tags: npx

Say I create a my-npx-hello-world repo

it has the following files

```
my-npx-hello-world/
      foo.sh
      index.sh
      package.json
```

the package.json has

```
  "bin": "./index.sh"
```

the index.sh calls ./foo.sh i.e.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "running foo"
./foo.sh
```

Now, when I try to run this

```
# npx my-npx-hello-world
running foo
line 4: ./foo.sh: No such file or directory
```

That is because it is looking for foo.sh in my CWD and not in the my-npx-hello-world repo.

What do I need to do so I can have the index.sh execute the foo.sh script in the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I resolved this by finding the CWD as below

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")/../lib/node_modules/my-npx-hello-worl
```

and then

```
cd $BASEDIR
./foo.sh
```